# How to replace a String from Arraylist without iteration In Grails?

Tags: grails, arraylist, groovy

I want to replace some Words in String without using any loops.

```
 def tagList= []
 def tags= []
 tags.each { tag ->
   def newString = tag.replaceAll("sample", "")
   tagList.add(newString)
 }
```

Comment: `tagList=tags.collect{ it.replaceAll("sample", "") }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the goodness of groovy you can directly replace string without iterating the List.

please try below code

```
 def tagList= []
 tagList = tags.join(',').replaceAll('sample','').split(',')
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be hard modify a list without iterating it (I assume, that this demand was just poorly phrased).  `each` is usually used for side-effects.  If you want to transform a list use `collect`.

If you only do one operation on each element, you can use the *Spread Operator* instead:

```
def tagList = tags*.replaceAll('sample', '')
```